# You can send letters priority post

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

Report

**Woman1**: I mail the letters. Sometimes I mail parcels to my friends may be in China or in the USA.

**Woman2**: I find the post office very useful to me. I go there most, almost everyday.

**Woman3**: Um, well, the only ones that I've used are sending parcels.

**Woman4**: You can send letters **priority post**. You can send them registered mail so you can always know where your letter is.

**Woman5**: Everything; I mail letters; I mail parcels; and use it money orders.

---

What does "**priority post**" mean?

Express or first class or registered mail?

Comment: Precisely what "priority, Express, first class, registered" might mean in relation to mail depends on exactly whereabouts in the world you are (and most people in most places probably wouldn't know the details anyway). All you can take for granted is that ***priority*** will have its normal dictionary-defined meaning - ***such letters are preferentially delivered faster / more securely.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Priority post** is mail that is given more priority than other items sent. It is used when someone wants their letter or package to arrive sooner (e.g. in 3 days instead of 7).

**Express** could mean higher priority than just "priority" but it could also mean the same thing. Each company decides what to call its own services and will specify how long the letter should take.

**First class** mail is mail that is given extra careful attention. This is usually very expensive (like 10 or 20 times) more expensive than sending a normal letter. It often requires signatures or confirmation of receipt and is tracked throughout the journey. It is used when someone sends expensive or sensitive documents that they want to be sure arrive where they need to be quickly and with near 100% certainty.

**Registered** mail is mail that is tracked and requires signature upon arrival so that the sender has confirmation that it is received. It also provides proof that the sent item has been sent. This is often used for legal purposes to proove in court that a letter has been sent to the recipient.

Comment: That's a useful answer, but in the UK, first-class mail is simply the name for what you call priority or express, doesn't require a signature and isn't tracked.

Comment: In the US as well, "first class" is standard mail that requires no confirmations and has no tracking. "Second class" is for periodical distribution (magazines and some newspapers), and third class mail is for bulk mail, which is to say, advertisements and general solicitations. "Express" and "priority" are marketing terms whose definition can change, but for the U.S. Postal Service, at present, "Express" carries a guarantee of overnight delivery, whereas "Priority" does not.